# Is there an alternative to Maven for .NET/Windows Forms projects?

Tags: c#, dependencies

What is used instead of [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) for C# Windows Forms projects?

We have developers all over the world and are trying to come up with some dependency management system that is clean simple and fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Maven alternative or port for the .NET world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652583/is-there-a-maven-alternative-or-port-for-the-net-world)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [Byldan](http://byldan.codeplex.com/), but the project seems quite young.

(See also Stack Overflow question *[Is there a Maven alternative or port for the .NET world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652583/is-there-a-maven-alternative-or-port-for-the-net-world)*.)

Comment: Byldan appears to not be in active development. Last commit was Dec. 2008

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a tutorial on the subject, *[Using Maven to manage .NET projects](https://web.archive.org/web/20110830022107/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+to+manage+.NET+projects)*.

Comment: Wish I found this after my disastrous attempt at porting C++ projects to it.  For fear of being accused of pimping you can find it at my blog (follow my profile for a link).

Answer (score 6):

It seems like there has been some work done in this area with [Nuget](http://nuget.org/). See David Ebbo's blogpost *[Using NuGet without committing packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html)*.

Answer (score 5):

There are [NMaven](http://nmaven.codeplex.com) and [NPanday](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/), and they both have the same origin. They are a collection of Maven plugins that enable a Maven-like built of C# and VB.NET projects.

NMaven seems dead, this is why I use NPanday. I recently joined the team, and it is quite active. The current release is 1.1. Version 1.2 is coming soon, and we are also working on the next major release.

**You should use it...**

- When you like Maven

**You shouldn't use it...**

- When you like MSBuild (this will become better in 2.0)
- When you need localized resource assemblies (will be fixed in 1.2)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) and write a plugin that integrates [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild).

We use Maven to manage non-Java components, such as our [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex) .swf and .swc modules. Writing a Maven plugin would be less effort than recreating a comparable system just for .NET assemblies.

I would recommend using [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) and Maven together, for that matter.