# Package Assemblies in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to have this sort of architecture with .NET assemblies:

I would like so store common assemblies (.dll) within a shared area (read only) where any application can access that particular file to make use of the utilities contained.

A practical example would be where the general assemblies package would contain utilities such as; auditing, database connection, security utilities, general utilities.

I would like that all these are packaged as a single item so it would be easier to reference and keep track of. Apart from that, we would like that the individual utilities can have different version numbers and this might be the tricky part. So if a particular person is using version 1, another might want to use version 2. All this, while everything is in the same 'package'.

This scenario is possible by using MAVEN in Java, but I am not sure which direction to go for when using .NET.

I would appreciate your feedback and suggestions.

Comment: This is a little too broad and subjective.  Do some research on Google, and then come back to [SO] if you have specific programming problems with the approach you decide on.

Answer (score 2):

Common area...like the GAC? Granted it doesn't package them up as a single item but it's designed to contain and manage assembly versions for you, pointless reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is [Nuget](http://nuget.org/). You can create your own package repository in local file system or some remote location and all clients may get the required dll via this package repository.

There are also other alternatives of Maven in .Net world mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652583/is-there-a-maven-alternative-or-port-for-the-net-world).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge multiple assemblies into one using a tool called ILMerge

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a plugin for .NET, which used to be called NMaven, but now is called NPanday. It is available at http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/.